# cleaning out a Mercurial Repository

Tags: version-control, mercurial

There are a bunch of file in the history of my hg repo that have been removed. They are causing the repo to get pretty big (several of them are images, and sql dumps from early in the project, among other things that never should have been comitted in the first place).

How do I get mercurial to forget about that stuff and get my repository down to a reasonable size again?

Should I just make a copy of the files (and the .hgignore) and make a new repo, while archiving the old one for future reference?

Comment: The MYYN has the right answer down below, but do be aware that in doing so you'll invalidate any clones anyone might have out there.  Since you're EditingHistory every node's hashid changes, so a previous clone that pushes or pulls would get a real mess.

Comment: @Ry4an good to know - Glad to have this disclaimer =). maybe I should look at a combination of archiving the old repo, and using MYYN's solution to create the repo for use moving forward - preserving history, but still starting fresh. Fortunately there are not many clones out in the wild. We'll just have to use traditional patches for those

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See:

```
$ hg convert --help
```

...

```
$ hg convert --filemap fmap old new
```

where file fmap contains something like:

```
exclude path/to/file/to/purge
```

(src: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2008-August/020721.html)