# delete files in history to save some space in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

ok, when I was young, I put severial big files(like resource file, dll, etc..) in my mercurial repos. and I found the size of it is so big that I cannot easily push it into bitbucket,

any way to delete this files history **EASILY**?

I put all those files in /res and /dll path.

edit:

this is a solution, but it will delete part of the history, so maybe there is a better solution.
[Mercurial Remove History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684898/mercurial-remove-history)

Comment: duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898600/cleaning-out-a-mercurial-repository

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the convert extension, but **warning** you'll end up with a totally different repo.  Every hash will be different and every person who cloned will need to delete their clone and re-clone.

That said, here's what you do:

Create a filemap file named `filemap.txt` containing:

```
exclude res
exclude dll
```

and then run this command:

```
hg convert --filemap filemap.txt your-source-repository your-destination-repository
```

For example:

```
hg convert --filemap filemap.txt /home/you/repos/bloatedrepo /home/you/repos/slenderrepo
```

That gets you a whole new repo that has all of your history except the history of any files in /res and /dll, but again it will be a new, unrelated repo as far as mercurial (and bitbucket) are concerned.

Comment: The convert switch isnt found for some reason has it been removed?

Comment: my bad you have to manually add the following in mercurial.ini before it will work
[extensions]
hgext.convert=

Comment: Looks like a good approach but would it still work if I want to remove specific files? Say a specific dll? Could you use?:

exclude MyDll.dll

Comment: Yes.  It's a "good approach" only if you're okay w/ having a different repository when you're done that's unrelated to the original in any way Mercurial can tell.  So everyone you work with will have to delete and re-clone.  That's fine for small teams or early on, but pretty much a "last resort" sort of thing in a larger setting.